# A question about primality

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any $n\ge2$, $\dfrac{2^{4n+2}+1}5$ isn't prime.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Did you also want to ask a question?

Comment: Cf. [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization)

Comment: I have tried it by searching two numbers that their product is equal with that expression,but I didn't found them.

Comment: I can't see a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$2^{4n+2}+1=(2^{2n+1}+2^{n+1}+1)(2^{2n+1}-2^{n+1}+1).$$

This is an [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization).

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{4n+2}+=(2^2)^{2n+1}+1=(5-1)^{2n+1}+1=5 k$$

$k=O(5, 2n+1)$

If $5|2n+1$ then $5|k$. This is condition for no-primality that says it is possible that $5|2n+1$ in which case the fraction will not be prime.

Comment: Your answer needs some editing (missing $1$ and $+1$), and even then it seems to show merely that $2^{4n+2}+1$ is divisible by $5$ and not answer OP's question

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, in your answer you also did not show how these factors are not prime.

Comment: OP asked to show that for any $n\ge2$, $\dfrac{2^{4n+2}+1}5$ isn't prime, and I gave a hint (factoring $2^{4n+2}+1$) to show that for any $n\ge2$